# Error in react-router-dom v6.2.2 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Iam using react-router-dom v6, I wrote the correct syntax but everytime iam getting this error. here is my complete App.js code.
iam getting this error "Error in react-router-dom v6.2.2 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"...

```
import $ from "jquery";
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Route, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import RenderForm from "./RenderForm";

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

require("jquery-ui-sortable");
require("formBuilder");

const formData = [];

export default class FormBuilder extends Component {
  fb = createRef();
  formBuilder = null;
  saveFile = () => {
    console.log(this.formBuilder.actions.getData());
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.formBuilder = $(this.fb.current).formBuilder({ formData });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="fb-editor" ref={this.fb} />
        <Link to="formdata">form structure</Link>
        <button onClick={this.saveFile}>save</button>

          <Routes>
            <Route path="/formdata" element={<RenderForm />} />
          </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**RenderForm.js**
"Error in react-router-dom v6.2.2 TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"...

```
import $ from "jquery";
import React, { createRef, Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

require("jquery-ui-sortable");
require("formBuilder");
require("formBuilder/dist/form-render.min.js");

const formData = [
  {
    type: "button",
    label: "Button",
    subtype: "button",
    className: "btn-default btn",
    name: "button-1647601287143-0",
    access: false,
    style: "default",
  },
  {
    type: "checkbox-group",
    required: false,
    label: "Checkbox Group",
    toggle: false,
    inline: false,
    name: "checkbox-group-1647601288538-0",
    access: false,
    other: false,
    values: [
      {
        label: "Option 1",
        value: "option-1",
        selected: true,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default class RenderForm extends Component {
  fb = createRef();

  formRenderOpts = {
    formData,
    dataType: "json",
  };
  fields = [
    {
      label: "Email",
      type: "text",
      subtype: "email",
      icon: "✉",
    },
  ];

  componentDidMount() {
    this.formRender = $(this.fb.current).formRender(this.formRenderOpts);
    console.log(this.formRender.options.formData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="fb-rendered-form" ref={this.fb} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error message properly and where you are using this?

Comment: its a very long message iam getting . initial part shared

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
useInRouterContext
C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/React/myproject/node_modules/react-router/index.js:289
  286 |  */
  287 | 
  288 | function useInRouterContext() {
> 289 |   return useContext(LocationContext) != null;
  290 | }
  291 | /**
  292 |  * Returns the current location object, which represents the current URL in web

Comment: try to wrap index.js with BrowserRouter and keep the routes on app.js

Comment: I am not sure, have to check your code, if possible share your code

Comment: Can you share the code for "./RenderForm"?

Comment: please check the code